# Failed to push some refs to Heroku due to requirement error

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm new to Django, and I was doing this task with the book Django for beginner, I did everything the book said but keep getting this error when I try to use git push Heroku master.
Here is the log:

```
Enumerating objects: 4, done.
    Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
    Delta compression using up to 4 threads
    Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 291 bytes | 145.00 KiB/s, done.
    Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
    remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), completed with 1 local object.
    To https://github.com/June907/pages-app.git
       c9ffa00..b1d98b4  master -> master
    Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'origin'.
    PS C:\Users\Assassin_yoo\Documents\github\bacs350\pages> git push heroku master
    Enumerating objects: 33, done.
    Counting objects: 100% (33/33), done.
    Delta compression using up to 4 threads
    Compressing objects: 100% (29/29), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (33/33), 5.91 KiB | 432.00 KiB/s, done.
    Total 33 (delta 6), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
    remote: Compressing source files... done.
    remote: Building source:
    remote:
    remote: -----> Python app detected
    remote: cp: cannot stat '/tmp/build_f896374c/requirements.txt': No such file or directory
    remote: -----> Installing python-3.8.5
    remote: -----> Installing pip 9.0.2, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
    remote: -----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 2018.5.18…
    remote:        Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (82e451)…
    remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
    remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
    remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
    remote:          File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    remote:            main()
    remote:          File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    remote:            utility.execute()
    remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    remote:            self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
    remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    remote:            self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
    remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    remote:            output = self.handle(*args, **options)
    remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 194, in handle
    remote:            collected = self.collect()
    remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 118, in collect
    remote:            handler(path, prefixed_path, storage)
    remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 345, in copy_file
    remote:            if not self.delete_file(path, prefixed_path, source_storage):
    remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 255, in delete_file
    remote:            if self.storage.exists(prefixed_path):
    remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 311, in exists
    remote:            return os.path.exists(self.path(name))
    remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 38, in path
    remote:            raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "
    remote:        django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.
    remote:
    remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
    remote:        See traceback above for details.
    remote:
    remote:        You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
    remote:        Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
    remote:
    remote:           $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
    remote:
    remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
    remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
    remote:
    remote:  !     Push failed
    remote: Verifying deploy...
    remote:
    remote: !       Push rejected to quiet-thicket-93045.
    remote:
    To https://git.heroku.com/quiet-thicket-93045.git
     ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/quiet-thicket-93045.git'
```

I did every step the book said, but I keep getting the error`cp: cannot stat '/tmp/build_f896374c/requirements.txt': No such file or directory`I'm not sure if I should create a requirments.txt?  I am really stuck now, please help.

Comment: by the way, the book said nothing about creating a requirment.txt, so I don't know if I should create it if I do where should I put it

Comment: This isn't a requirements error. You're using Pipenv, which supersedes `pip` and `requirements.txt`. The actual error here is `raise ImproperlyConfigured("You're using the staticfiles app "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having set the STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImproperlyConfigured staticfiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32790009/improperlyconfigured-staticfiles)